# unable to display value in erb using ruby/sinatra

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, erb

I have two model classes - Admin and Bill.  I am able to get them from the database using ActiveRecord but when I use an erb template, I cannot display the bills information (each admin can have multiple bills):

**app.rb**

```
  get '/admins/:id' do
        @admin = Admin.find_by(id:params[:id])
        @bills = Bill.find_by(user_id:params[:id])
        erb :adminDetails
  end
```

**adminDetails.erb**

```
<ul>
    <li>full name: <%=@admin.name %></li>
    <li>email: <%=@admin.email %></li>
        <% @bills.each do |bill| %>
        <li>bill title: <%=bill.title %></li>
        <li>bill body: <%=bill.body %></li>
         <% end %>
</ul>
```

I can print out the bill info via irb but when I pass it into the erb template, I get the following exception:

```
WARN: tilt autoloading 'tilt/erb' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'tilt/erb' suggested.
2015-09-10 05:00:26 - NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for #<Bill id: 1, admin_id: 1, title: "test1", body: "this is test1">:
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
        /opt/test/ruby/7/views/adminDetails.erb:11:in `block in singleton class'
        /opt/test/ruby/7/views/adminDetails.erb:-6:in `instance_eval'
        /opt/test/ruby/7/views/adminDetails.erb:-6:in `singleton class'
        /opt/test/ruby/7/views/adminDetails.erb:-8:in `__tilt_20667340'
```

**Bill Model**

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :admin
end
```

Is there something wrong with my setup causing this issue?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You trying to make an iteration through an one record. `Bill.find_by(user_id:params[:id])` returns only an one record(first matched), fix your code to:

```
@bills = Bill.where(user_id: params[:id])
```

Read the documentation for [`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) and [`find_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by)

Comment: thank you.  any idea on why the erb will not even show the one value

Comment: `each` for iteration through collection, to show one value, use a variable and `find_by` without `each` in view

Answer (score 1):

Your instance variable `@bills` might not be enumerable. In other words `@bills` might not be array of entity `Bill`.

You're trying to iterate over

```
<Bill id: 1, admin_id: 1, title: "test1", body: "this is test1">
```

not even

```
[#<Bill id: 1, admin_id: 1, title: "test1", body: "this is test1">]
```

and that's because `find_by` returns just first matching record based on the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take bills from your `@admin` variable?
You don't need `@bills` in your controller anymore:

```
  get '/admins/:id' do
        @admin = Admin.find_by(id:params[:id])
        erb :adminDetails
  end
```

And use this for your template:

```
  <% @admin.bills.each do |bill| %>
    <li>bill title: <%=bill.title %></li>
    <li>bill body: <%=bill.body %></li>
   <% end %>
```